# How collapse all ng-js-tree nodes programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jstree

I using ng-js-tree https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree
I loading tree from json and trying to collapse all nodes using two ways(state.opened and close_all):

```
    $http.get('resources/json/mkb10.json')
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.cond.treeData = res.data;
        if (data !== undefined){

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cond.treeData.length; i++){
                $scope.cond.treeData[i].state = {};
                for (var j = 0; j < data.cond.length; j++)
                    if ($scope.cond.treeData[i].id == data.cond[j]){
                        $scope.cond.treeData[i].state = {selected: true};
                    }
                $scope.cond.treeData[i].state.opened = false;
            }
        }
        $scope.treeInstance.jstree(true).close_all();
        $scope.treeConfig.version++;
        $scope.treeInstance.jstree(true).close_all();
    });
```

my result is:
 [image]

But both of them no needed result.
Who know, how collapse all nodes? Thanks!

I writed [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CVdqRnElOJF5hNADdKih?p=preview) for example

I want to get this view:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced jstree.js to 3.0.8 and win this)

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree/master/demo/bower_components/jstree/dist/jstree.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://rawgit.com/vakata/jstree/master/dist/jstree.js"></script-->
```

[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/CVdqRnElOJF5hNADdKih?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the ready event of the tree before using the tree api.
Check the code of the demo age on GitHub:
https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree

Also when you increase the version you are recreating the tree, I don't think this is what you meant to do.

If this is not helping you, please write a plunker and share it so i will be able to help you

Comment: in plunker showed tree with selected nodes, why selected is opened? I want to close all nodes programmatically, manually i can do this.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the js tree... i replaced the method with check_all for example and it is working.... The closing is done by the js tree itself.

Comment: Where is example? Link please?